Qiskit controlled phase shift gates aren't placing superposition states where I'd expect
When I put my qubits into a superposition and apply several controlled phase shifts, when I try to visualize the state they're in, qiskit shows them as all over the Bloch sphere, rather than around the horizontal axis like I'd expect.
Thinking I got the math wrong, I tried adjusting the denominator in the CPhaseGate, but to my surprise, that didn't have any effect either.
What am I missing?

Reproduction code:
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.visualization import plot_state_qsphere
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
qc.h(0)
qc.h(1)
qc.h(2)
qc.h(3)
qc.cz(1,3)
cphase_gate = CPhaseGate(np.pi / 2)
qc.append(cphase_gate, [0, 1])
qc.append(cphase_gate, [0, 3])
qc.append(cphase_gate, [1, 2])
qc.append(cphase_gate, [2, 3])
# I've also tried using the cz gates instead but got the same behavior:
# qc.cz(0,3)
# qc.cz(1,2)
# qc.cz(2,3)
state = Statevector(qc)
plot_state_qsphere(state)

